# Changing additional requirements in join clause to case statement

Tags: sql-server, join, case

In my query I have various joins and additional restrictions to the joins. The one I want to focus on is this:

```
INNER JOIN PerfLevelReportBandComponents bandComponents ON bandComponents.fkPerformanceLevelReportBandID = bands.pkPerformanceLevelReportBandID 
    AND ((bandComponents.ScoreValue = StudentScores_Subject.ScoreValue))
    OR ((CAST(StudentScores_Subject.ScoreValue AS INT) BETWEEN bandComponents.minScore and bandComponents.maxScore)
    OR (CAST(StudentScores_Subject.ScoreValue AS INT) BETWEEN cutScores.minScore and cutScores.maxScore))
```

The column `StudentScores_Subject.ScoreValue` could be compared in `bandComponents.ScoreValue`, `bandComponents.minScore` / `bandComponents.maxScore`, or `cutScores.minScore` / `cutScores.maxScore`. If the `StudentScores_Subject.ScoreValue` is an integer value, such as a number between 0-99 its a given that the value could be compared by any of these `AND` or `OR`s , but I won't know which one its comparing each time depending on other restrictions not important to the question, so bottom line is I won't know which `AND` or `OR` it will be using to create the restriction, so I need all these additional statements in the join. Typically in the past, `StudentScores_Subject.ScoreValue` contained student scores which were only be numerical values so I had no problem with the restrictions in the join, but now the values can be strings, such as "FBB" (far below basic) or even "P" (pass). Now there is always an error with string scores converting to ints in the casts, but this does not need to be because if the value is a string its always a given that the only restriction that needs to run is `AND ((bandComponents.ScoreValue = StudentScores_Subject.ScoreValue))`. So my question is, is there any way to turn these extra restrictions in the joins to some sort of a case statement so if values are strings they won't hit the two second `OR`s, but if the score values are integers they can hit those extra restrictions. Here is the full query:

```
SELECT MM_SchoolYears.pkSchoolYearID, TestInstances.pkTestInstanceID, StudentScores_Subject.fkTest_SubjectID, 0 AS 'fkDemographicCodeID', SUM(CASE WHEN bands.StackPosition = '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100.0/ CASE WHEN COUNT(pkStudentScoreID) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE COUNT(pkStudentScoreID) END AS 'Percent_0', SUM(CASE WHEN bands.StackPosition = '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Count_0', (SELECT bb.pkPerformanceLevelReportBandID FROM PerformanceLevelReportBands bb WHERE bb.fkPerformanceLevelReportID = '6' AND bb.StackPosition = '0') AS 'BandID_0', SUM(CASE WHEN bands.StackPosition = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100.0/ CASE WHEN COUNT(pkStudentScoreID) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE COUNT(pkStudentScoreID) END AS 'Percent_1', SUM(CASE WHEN bands.StackPosition = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Count_1', (SELECT bb.pkPerformanceLevelReportBandID FROM PerformanceLevelReportBands bb WHERE bb.fkPerformanceLevelReportID = '6' AND bb.StackPosition = '1') AS 'BandID_1' 
        FROM StudentScores_Subject
                INNER JOIN StudentTests ON StudentScores_Subject.fkStudentTestID = StudentTests.pkStudentTestID
                INNER JOIN TestInstances ON  TestInstances.pkTestInstanceID = StudentTests.fkTestInstanceID
                INNER JOIN CAHSEE_TestPeriods ON CAHSEE_TestPeriods.pkTestPeriodID = TestInstances.fkTestPeriodID   
                INNER JOIN PerformanceLevelReportBands bands ON bands.fkPerformanceLevelReportID = @intPerfLevelReportId
                LEFT JOIN MMARS_Web_TestInfo_California.dbo.PerfLevelReportBandCutScores cutScores ON cutScores.fkPerformanceLevelReportBandID = bands.pkPerformanceLevelReportBandID
                    AND cutScores.fkGradeID = @intGradeId
                    AND cutScores.fkTestSubjectID IN (SELECT id FROM @tempSubs)
                INNER JOIN PerfLevelReportBandComponents bandComponents ON bandComponents.fkPerformanceLevelReportBandID = bands.pkPerformanceLevelReportBandID 
                    AND ((bandComponents.ScoreValue = StudentScores_Subject.ScoreValue))
                    OR ((CAST(StudentScores_Subject.ScoreValue AS INT) BETWEEN bandComponents.minScore and bandComponents.maxScore)
                    OR (CAST(StudentScores_Subject.ScoreValue AS INT) BETWEEN cutScores.minScore and cutScores.maxScore))
                RIGHT JOIN MM_SchoolYears ON MM_SchoolYears.pkSchoolYearID = TestInstances.fkSchoolYearID
        WHERE MM_SchoolYears.pkSchoolYearID IN (SELECT number FROM itot(@strYearIds, N','))
                AND bands.fkPerformanceLevelReportID = @intPerfLevelReportId
                AND StudentScores_Subject.fkStudentTestID IN (SELECT id FROM @tempTests)
                AND StudentScores_Subject.fkScoreTypeID = bandComponents.fkScoreTypeID
                AND StudentScores_Subject.fkTest_SubjectID IN (SELECT id FROM @tempSubs)
                AND (bandComponents.ScoreValue = StudentScores_Subject.ScoreValue)
        GROUP BY MM_SchoolYears.pkSchoolYearID, TestInstances.pkTestInstanceID, StudentScores_Subject.fkTest_SubjectID
        ORDER BY MM_SchoolYears.pkSchoolYearID, TestInstances.pkTestInstanceID, StudentScores_Subject.fkTest_SubjectID
```

The long select statement is dynamically created and just creates counts, and percents for the sets of students, but shouldn't be important to the question.

Comment: You could turn them into cases, but given the complexity of your query, I think you might be better off either pre-calculating results (have a job, so you can query results easier) or try to split it into multiple queries doing a union together; simply to get rid of the 'OR' logic which easily can cause havoc with execution plans in sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extend join condition a bit with an addition `ISNUMERIC` check like this:

```
INNER JOIN PerfLevelReportBandComponents bandComponents ON bandComponents.fkPerformanceLevelReportBandID = bands.pkPerformanceLevelReportBandID 
  AND ((bandComponents.ScoreValue = StudentScores_Subject.ScoreValue))
  OR
  (
    ISNUMERIC(StudentScores_Subject.ScoreValue)
    AND
    (
      (CAST(StudentScores_Subject.ScoreValue AS INT) BETWEEN bandComponents.minScore and bandComponents.maxScore)
      OR
      (CAST(StudentScores_Subject.ScoreValue AS INT) BETWEEN cutScores.minScore and cutScores.maxScore)
    )
   )
```

This is not fool proof - there are many discussion out there why ISNUMERIC does not guarantee that CAST to int will work or the other way around, but in your case it may be sufficient to solve your problem.

Comment: Hey this worked well for me. I know there is the try_convert in sql server 2012, but I am using 2008, but this works fine, thanks.